# HTML5 Drag and Drop access Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I was studying Drag and Drop to implement on a project, got it to work using HTML5 as you can see on this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/leofontes/pen/aNQpWO) but I need it to be more complex to use on my project, specially to be able to access the data-property of the dragged object.

This is the HTML

```
<section class="sectionOne">

    <div draggable="true" class="sec-one-div" ondrag="dragCheck(event);" ondragstart="dragStart(event);" data-somedata="300">
        <p>This is section one</p>
    </div>

    </section>
<section class="sectionTwo" ondrop="drop(event);" ondragover="dragover(event);" id="secTwo">

    <p>This is section two</p>

</section>
<section class="sectionThree" >

    <p>This is section three</p>

</section>
```

The JS

```
function dragCheck(ev) {
    console.log("im dragging");
}

function dragStart(ev) {
    console.log('drag start');
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", "this is some text");
}

function dragover(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    // Set the dropEffect to move
    ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move"
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    console.log('drop');
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData('text');
    $('#secTwo').append('hahaaha');
}
```

I need to access the 'data-somedata' attribute of the div that was dragged (on my project I'll need 5 of them but for now 1 will do) so that I can append the correct values on another element. How can I do that?

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) wasn't clear to me what I should use to obtain this result, all help is appreciated. If more information is necessary, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event contains the target dragged element, so you can get the attribute for that element using:

```
function dragCheck(ev) {
  console.log("im dragging");
  console.log(ev.target.getAttribute("data-someinfo"));
}
```

or with jQuery:

```
function dragCheck(ev) {
  console.log("im dragging");
  console.log($(ev.target).attr('data-someinfo'));
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much, I knew it wasn't anything extra hard but I was trying to access the attribute in a bad way.